# Conversion from CURL to PHP Curl

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I am running the below Curl request and it's working.

```
curl -v --cert /path/to/certs/myCert.crt --key  /path/to/key/myKey.key --cacert /path/to/chainedcerts/intermediary.pem  https://mysite:30009/
```

Converting it to php as below and it's failing with error 77 with no narration. I am thinking probably file permissions could be the issue. I am using nginx and the 3 certs are owned by nginx user. If there is any other way I can view the error description as I can see the other errors

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "xmlRequest=" . $xml);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Expect:','Content-Type: text/xml']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT,  "/path/to/certs/myCert.crt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY,  "/path/to/key/myKey.key");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/path/to/chainedcerts/intermediary.pem "); 
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        Log::error($httpcode .' : '. curl_errno($ch) .' : '. curl_error($ch));
        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: thats a problem verifying certificates. is it a self signed cert?

Comment: if so, dont verify peer/host, set those false

Comment: It's self signed. I am concerned about MITM attack when I turn verify peer/host to false. But either way I get an error. 35 client certificate not found

Comment: 35? you said your error was 77

Comment: is the self signed on dev? you have a proper cert on production?

Comment: @delboy1978uk when I set the values to false. The error changes to 35. The issue s the API server I am posting to is using selfsigned SSLs.

Comment: see if this helps https://blogs.agilefaqs.com/2013/11/25/curl-35-unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection/